# jQuery - left click context menu plugin

Tags: jquery, click, contextmenu

I am looking for something that has similar functionality like context menu on dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a boat load of them: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/context-menu

In particular, this one is awesome: http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdContextMenu/sample.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this plugin: [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be a hidden div that is shown at the onclick event.